# does it possile rails declare gem should update automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a rails project that have alot of gems, whitch works on server, few days ago I decide to update my project to latest version of rails and gems then I found some gems in my project depricated and I have to refactore my code.
Then i found does it possilbe to change some configuretions in my rails project to declare me when should I update gems in gemfiles or i have to check my gemfile manually to be sure my project up to date?

I google my idea but nothings found useful witch can help me

Comment: you can call `bundler outdated` to get a list of all gems that have newer versions. Or you can use a service like https://dependabot.com/ to update your gems automatically when possible.

Comment: Also, to be clear: `rails` is just a web framework, written in `ruby`. It is not the job of `rails` to inform you of when other libraries are out of date... this would be like whatsapp on your phone informing you when snapchat is out of date; it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is possible by rails configuration. rails or gems used will usually log deprecated messages if they intend to deprecate any feature.

however, there are other free apps that can do similar things like https://depfu.com/ which will depend on how you set your configuration, open a PR with gems that need updates

there is also https://dependabot.com/ by Github which also has the power (if your project is on any git platform) to show you messages on which gem needs a security update or is being deprecated in the security tab

[image]